# How to index string using map function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this list as an input but i want to give each alphabet an index
for example  k = 1  , i = 2  , s = 3 , s=3 ,a = 4

```
['k', 'i', 's', 's', 'a']
```

is there way to use map function effectively in this case

I have tried to use map function but it returns

```
<map object at 0x0000015513F6B4C0>
```

which is not readble even using list()

Comment: What should happen in the case `['k', 'i', 's', 's', 'a', 'i']`, for example?

Comment: how did you use `map`? Better show what you tried to do.

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = ['k', 'i', 's', 's', 'a']

c = defaultdict(list)

for idx, el in enumerate(l):
    c[el].append(idx)

print(c) # defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'k': [0], 'i': [1], 's': [2, 3], 'a': [4]})
```

You can now get all the indexes of a given element, e.g. `c['s']` will return you a list of `[2, 3]`

Comment: This is good. Pretty general. In a second step the OP can select (AFAIU) the first item of the list-value and add "+1" if things should start at "1".

Comment: @Brandt I have just noticed that this actually isn't what OP wants, (`s = 3 , s=3 ,a = 4`), but it's not really clear to me how does that expected output work.

Comment: Well, with your code the OP can then refine to his/her purpose. I would add (from where you left): `{e:c[e][0]+1 for e in l}`; resulting in `# {'k': 1, 'i': 2, 's': 3, 'a': 5}`

Comment: Or, instead, simply: `[c[e][0]+1 for e in l]` (rsulting in `[1, 2, 3, 3, 5]`).  (full story: `list(zip(l,[c[e][0]+1 for e in l]))`)

Comment: I think OP is looking for index of unique characters. i.e. `{'k': 1, 'i': 2, 's': 3, 'a': 4}` . Check my below answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's an *one liner* to achieve this via using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) along with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) as:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> my_list = ['k', 'i', 's', 's', 'a']

>>> {x[0]: i for i, x in enumerate(groupby(my_list), 1)}
{'k': 1, 'i': 2, 's': 3, 'a': 4}
```

However above approach is not optimal from performance point of view. Here's simpler implementation using a counter and an explicit `for` loop:

```
count = 1
my_dict = {}
my_list = ['k', 'i', 's', 's', 'a']

for x in my_list:
    if x not in my_dict:
        my_dict[x] = count
        count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# you can use dictionary datatype in python which maps key and value.
a = {'k':1, 'i':2, 's':3, 'a':4,}
```

Comment: bro i want that if there is same alphabet it gets same value

Comment: You cannot use a dictionary with duplicated keys. The result is not well-defined. This is wrong.

Comment: so.you want to use duplicate keys as well right?

Answer (score 0):

you can go with this approach solution-1

#### input

```
def myfunc(a, b):
  return (a,b)

a= ['k', 'i', 's', 's', 'a','w']
b = list(range(1,len(a)+1))

x = map(myfunc, a, b)
print(list(x))
```

#### output

```
[('k', 1), ('i', 2), ('s', 3), ('s', 4), ('a', 5), ('w', 6)]
```

### NOTE:- if you go with a dictionary then the duplicate key not take for the index

i.e. - in your case in the list have two times (s) character you go with dictionary then (s) character indexed only one time

#### Solution - 2 with string

```
def myfunc(a, b):
  return (a,b)


p= 'kissa' 
b = list(range(1,len(list(p))+1))

x = map(myfunc, list(p), b)
print(list(x)) # return list of tupel

Output - [('k', 1), ('i', 2), ('s', 3), ('s', 4), ('a', 5), ('n', 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to store your custom index.

Here is a simple code example:

```
arr = ['k', 'i', 's', 's', 'a']

# dictionary format:
# { 'your_cumtom_index' : default_index(0, 1, 2,...) }
idx = {'myId-1': 0,
       'myId-2': 1,
       'myId-3': 2,
       'myId-4': 3,
       'myId-5': 4
       }

print(arr[idx['myId-2']])
```